# while scraping i am getting some junk value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi All please check the below code using bs4 to scrape the webpage.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.nfl.com/standings/league/2019/REG'
page = requests.get('https://www.nfl.com/standings/league/2019/REG')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

#Subsets the HTML to only get the HTML of our table needed
table = soup.find('table', {'summary':'Standings - Detailed View'})

#Gets all the column headers of our table
headers = []
for i in table.find_all('th'):
    title = i.text.strip()
    headers.append(title)

#Creates a dataframe using the column headers from our table
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

#gets all our data within the table and adds it to our dataframe
for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    #line below fixes the formatting issue  with the team names
    first_td = row.find_all('td')[0].find('div', class_ = 'd3-o-club-fullname').text.strip()
    data = row.find_all('td')[1:]
    row_data = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
    row_data.insert(0,first_td)
    length = len(df)
    df.loc[length] = row_data

df.to_csv('F:/beautiful soup/tablefg.csv')
```

After running the above code i am getting the values as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDFEp.png)

in this image for 0 value i am getting as 2000. Dont know why it's showing so. it should 03-03-0 but getting output as 03-03-2000

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pandas, you don't need to make table parsing so difficult. You can simply do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://www.nfl.com/standings/league/2019/REG')[0]
df.to_csv('F:/beautiful soup/tablefg.csv')
```